# VBA - Find Row from Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I've been down this road before.  Match function worked when I was using a single criteria, but I'm not able to use it properly using two criterias.

My current procedure looks on the NR_Qualtrics page to find a match on CaseID and Email.  Because the columns for these can be different based on each document I get, I have procedure that identifies the row and returns which range CaseID and Email is in.

The next thing I'm doing in this function is iterating through each of the rows in NonResidential sheet trying to find a match on CaseID and Email.  I need the function to return the row that the match was found on and report that in column O.  Currently, I'm still stuck trying to find the matching columns.  I keep getting Error 2015 and Error 2029 when I'm debugging.  I'm sure that the matches exist when I look through it manually.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with my procedure.  Can you please help?

```
Sub NonResFindMultipleProviders()
    'This function finds any duplicate Case IDs for NR providers where they had surveys
    'This function needs to run before NonRes_ChkSurveyRcd
    'If there are duplicates, it will indicate that in the Notes Column (N)
    'If a duplicate exists, then it must match on Email and CaseID and show the value of Yes-NR_Qualtrics Row XX/No in Survey Recieved (Column O)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim r, lastRow, rowMatch As Long
    Dim colCaseID, colEmail, colResponseID As Long
    Dim rngCaseID, rngEmail, rngResponseID As Range
    Dim valEmail, valCaseID As String
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim shtNR As Worksheet
    Dim shtQNR As Worksheet

    Sheets("NonResidential").Select
    lastRow = getLastRow

    Range("A2").Select

    Set shtNR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NonResidential")
    Set shtQNR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NR_Qualtrics")

    colCaseID = FindColHeaderWText("NR_Qualtrics", "ExternalDataReference")
    Set rngCaseID = Worksheets("NR_Qualtrics").Columns(colCaseID)
    colEmail = FindColHeaderWText("NR_Qualtrics", "EmailAddress")
    Set rngEmail = Worksheets("NR_Qualtrics").Columns(colEmail)
    'colResponseID = FindColHeaderWText("NR_Qualtrics", "ResponseID")
    'Set rngResponseID = Worksheets("NR_Qualtrics").Columns(colResponseID)

    'The Notes field(column N) shows the duplicates.  Find matches on CaseID AND Email
    ''Not (IsError(Application.Match(Cells(r, 1).Value, rng, 0))) And
    For r = 2 To lastRow
        valCaseID = Cells(r, 1).Value   'Column A (1) has CaseIDs
        valEmail = Cells(r, 12).Value   'Column L (12) has emails

        result = shtNR.Evaluate("MATCH(" & valCaseID & "&" & valEmail & ",rngCaseID&rngEmail,0)")
        If (Not IsError(result)) Then    'Mark only if Notes - Column N (13) is marked with a duplicate - Need to put this in next.  RN, just evaluate everything
            Cells(r, 15).Value = "Yes"  'Column O (14) Survey Recieved marked with Yes
        End If
    Next r

    'Cleanup - Remove the words duplicate
    'Columns("N:N").Select
    'Selection.Replace What:="Duplicate", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    '    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    '    ReplaceFormat:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What lines throw the errors?

Comment: All of them it seems.  I put the "debug.print r" inside of the if statement and didn't get any results.  When I put: "Debug.Print result & "-" & r " above the if statement, after the results.  I get an run-time error '13' Type mismatch.

Comment: Why are `rngCaseID` and `rngEmail` within quotes in `result = shtNR.Evaluate("MATCH(" & valCaseID & "&" & valEmail & ",rngCaseID&rngEmail,0)")`?

Comment: I don't think they're in quotes.  Are they supposed to be in quotes?

Comment: They are inside the quotes and as such are no longer variables but strings.

Comment: I was able to find results being returned for: 
=INDEX(NR_Qualtrics!$A:$A,MATCH(1, (NonResidential!A166=NR_Qualtrics!$I:$I) * (NonResidential!L166=NR_Qualtrics!$H:$H),0))


But when I put the following code, I didn't get any results: 
result = shtNR.Evaluate("=INDEX(NR_Qualtrics!$A:$A,MATCH(1, (NonResidential!" & r & "=NR_Qualtrics!$I:$I) * (NonResidential!L" & r & "=NR_Qualtrics!$H:$H),0))")

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that matches based on 3 criteria.  Try dropping your ranges and criteria into this:

```
Sub MatchMultipleCritera()

    ' Cells containing the values to match
    Dim criteria1 As Range, criteria2 As Range, criteria3 As Range
    Set criteria1 = Range("A1")
    Set criteria2 = Range("B1")
    Set criteria3 = Range("C1")


    ' Ranges containing the values to be checked against the match values above.
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range("Table1[Item]")
    Set rng2 = Range("Table1[Active]")
    Set rng3 = Range("Table1[Quanitity2]")

    MsgBox "Row " & Evaluate("=MATCH(1,(" & criteria1.Address & "=" & rng1.Address & ")*(" & criteria2.Address & "=" & rng2.Address & ")*(" & criteria3.Address & "=" & rng3.Address & "))")
End Sub
```

In this example:

- Cells A1, B1 and C1 contain the values I am matching.
- I am looking in a table (`Excel.ListObject`) named "Table1" that has columns "Item", "Active" and "Quantity".
- `rng1` is checked for the value in `criteria1`, `rng2` for `criteria2`, etc.
- The result is the row number.

This is a VBA modification of [this ExcelJet article](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria) using array formulas.  The `Evaluate` function evaluates formulas as array formulas by default

Comment: Thanks for this.  But when I ran it, All of the results (found or not found) returned: "Row 1048576"